# How may I add a button into ejs file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

So I do have a list containing 8 to 10 elements maximum and I want to add a button in a certain ejs page depending on how many items do I have on the list. for example : ["Salad","Tomato","Paste"] then 3 buttons will be added on the page and so on...

```
app.post('wanttogo', function (req, res) {

});
```

the above is the post function in which the implementation is needed
is there such thing as I described in javascript to dynamically add a button depending on loop or something.
Thanks in advance,

I have little knowledge on javascript and I tried to google what I want but the results where amibiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let buttons_from_post = ["Salad","Tomato","Paste"];
 
buttons_from_post.forEach(addBtn);




function addBtn(value, index, array) {
  let btn = document.createElement("button");
  btn.innerHTML = value;
  btn.onclick = function () {
    alert("Button is clicked");
  };
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
```

here is an example of doing so